# memory "used" and indicated in "ps" doesn't add up

Tags: memory-usage

I cannot track of memory used in my system. "System monitor" graphical tool tells that I use 18GB of memory.
[image]

Then "top" tell me 16.4GB

[image]

htop - 6.94 GB
[image]

The command:

```
ps aux | awk '{s+=$6} END{print s/1024/1024}'
```

Tells me 9.32965 GB used.

```
root@testo:~# cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       32777232 kB
MemFree:        15718012 kB
MemAvailable:   17225504 kB
Buffers:             112 kB
Cached:          2040884 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           692532 kB
Inactive:        6150240 kB
Active(anon):       3324 kB
Inactive(anon):  5011996 kB
Active(file):     689208 kB
Inactive(file):  1138244 kB
Unevictable:       17864 kB
Mlocked:           17864 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               112 kB
Writeback:           180 kB
AnonPages:       4819744 kB
Mapped:          1252384 kB
Shmem:            207228 kB
KReclaimable:     115868 kB
Slab:            1837584 kB
SReclaimable:     115868 kB
SUnreclaim:      1721716 kB
KernelStack:       23680 kB
PageTables:        54112 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    16388616 kB
Committed_AS:   14900136 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      732216 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:            48384 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:    16638844 kB
DirectMap2M:    16822272 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

What is going on? I do not understand the discrepancy between the around 9GB used and the 18GB. Thing is that this is Ubuntu which is basically turned on, with Evolution and web browser opened.

Edit:
I did a fresh reboot, and the amount of memory used dropped from 18GB to 6 GB. (with same applications open). I compared the /proc/meminfo, and I see the differences (first column: after restart, second column before restart):

```
DirectMap4k:        16638844     1436540
DirectMap2M:        16822272     11053056
DirectMap1G:        0            20971520
```

and:

```
Slab:               1837584      825116
SReclaimable:       115868       142748
SUnreclaim:         1721716      682368
```

and:

```
MemTotal:           32777232     32777236
MemFree:            15718012     23822224
MemAvailable:       17225504     27557084
Buffers:            112          30384
Cached:             2040884      4018376
SwapCached:         0            0
Active:             692532       1144872
Inactive:           6150240      4743716
Active(anon):       3324         2736
Inactive(anon):     5011996      1858808
Active(file):       689208       1142136
Inactive(file):     1138244      2884908
```

** EDit (26/03/2022) **
Below I paste the /proc/meminfo with 3rd column showing same data as in 2nd column bu after a computer restart. In both cases system was brought to "systemctl start multi-user", and to my best knowledge the same software is running on it (no GUI for example). The difference is that restart cleared something. Is it apparent from this what leads to the huge difference in "used" memory (4GB in after and close to 16GB  before the restart). Is it obvious what is the main contributor to the much smaller MemFree and MemAvailable before the restart (I guess one has to know how to add/subtract these lines)?

```
MemTotal:           32777236kB     32777236kB
MemFree:            15401852kB     28025100kB
MemAvailable:       18405812kB     29808364kB
Buffers:            2360kB         25500kB
Cached:             3549100kB      2082168kB
SwapCached:         0kB            0kB
Active:             1091844kB      293272kB
Inactive:           2731276kB      2388616kB
Active(anon):       1424kB         2332kB
Inactive(anon):     326200kB       584700kB
Active(file):       1090420kB      290940kB
Inactive(file):     2405076kB      1803916kB
Unevictable:        17784kB        18044kB
Mlocked:            17784kB        18044kB
SwapTotal:          0kB            0kB
SwapFree:           0kB            0kB
Dirty:              62472kB        2912kB
Writeback:          0kB            0kB
AnonPages:          289404kB       592340kB
Mapped:             143940kB       187624kB
Shmem:              49612kB        6444kB
KReclaimable:       142288kB       103936kB
Slab:               969604kB       609656kB
SReclaimable:       142288kB       103936kB
SUnreclaim:         827316kB       505720kB
KernelStack:        10448kB        11040kB
PageTables:         9592kB         9204kB
NFS_Unstable:       0kB            0kB
Bounce:             0kB            0kB
WritebackTmp:       0kB            0kB
CommitLimit:        16388616kB     16388616kB
Committed_AS:       2309600kB      2151884kB
VmallocTotal:       34359738367kB  34359738367kB
VmallocUsed:        1019352kB      308136kB
VmallocChunk:       0kB            0kB
Percpu:             46592kB        37120kB
HardwareCorrupted:  0kB            0kB
AnonHugePages:      0kB            0kB
ShmemHugePages:     0kB            0kB
ShmemPmdMapped:     0kB            0kB
FileHugePages:      0kB            0kB
FilePmdMapped:      0kB            0kB
HugePages_Total:    0              0
HugePages_Free:     0              0
HugePages_Rsvd:     0              0
HugePages_Surp:     0              0
Hugepagesize:       2048kB         2048kB
Hugetlb:            0kB            0kB
DirectMap4k:        12815228kB     531324kB
DirectMap2M:        20645888kB     6715392kB
DirectMap1G:        0kB            26214400kB
```

** EDIT (29/03/2022) **
Output of free -m (now everything tells me that nearly all of the memory is used. I have web browser open, gedit, a couple of terminals and that is it.

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           32009       29235         915         681        1857        1632
Swap:              0           0           0
```

Comment: This is a problem going back decades, as memory can be both *free* (available for apps if they malloc() it) and used (as cache; to aid in system performance, but that cache will be lost the moment an app requests RAM)...

Comment: Ok, but my top says "used" aroung 16GB,  "free" around 8GB, and another 8GB for cache. In total there is 32GB these values add up together to 32GB as if they were pretty exclusive.

Comment: My point is there was much debate for decades on how to calculate used space (1970s, into 1980s) & no method won out.. so different tools will calculate it differently (*according to what they feel is the best/most-correct method*)   Someone will *find* a duplicate for this question & post it; I don't have time to look currently sorry.

Comment: Most of these questions are only superficially similar - they deal with older reporting methods, or people sum up wrong column.

Comment: There is _no real answer_ to this question. I tend to use the formula: **MemoryUsed=MemTotal-MemAvailable** (as reported by `/proc/meminfo`). Feel free to use whatever method is provided in other answers _that fits to your head_! :)

Comment: Worse, the "shared" column represents used memory that doesn't show up in RSS, but ps doesn't have a way to determine which processes are sharing that memory so it either doesn't get counted at all (as you've done) or it gets counted multiple times with no way to fix it.   You can't calculate total memory used by looking at what individual processes are using.  That's why the kernel publishes totals separately.

Comment: Ok, then how do I figure out wwhere memory is used? Now the thing is that 32GB of RAM seems to be not enough for the machine, as "something" is eating up the RAM.  If I turn off literary everything with "systemctl start multi-user.target" i am still using 15GB of ram (using as in "used"), and after a restart it drops down to 2GB (with multi-usertarget). The use seems real as when "used" goes up to 32GB with UI the system starts to swap memory on a HDD and is slow.

Comment: All I do on this computer is sshing to computer at work, use Google-Chrome, use email client evolution. It seems to me 32GB should be enough...

Comment: All web browsers gobble memory.  But are you looking at the right column?  Because cache *should* fill all memory and it isn't an issue.  You can use top or atop and sort by RSS or VSZ and find your big memory processes.  Just don't expect the numbers to add up and make sense as totals.

Comment: Point is that without GUI (thus without web-browser) the RAM usage was still 13-16GB, after restart - just 3 or less. No significant memory used by individual software shown in htop, atop or whatever.

Comment: You are probably looking at cache usage, which you should ignore.

Comment: except things I have posted explicitly list cache usage separately and that is not it (cache is listed separately from "used"). I basically noticed that downloading files from the web browser (Firefox or Chrome) increases the "used" memory, after file is downloaded and browser turned off, the "used" memory remains.  However  memory is seems to be freed when needed. I am still testing this new discovery. So some sort of "cache" is likely the thing, but not the "cache" listed in top.

Comment: Can you add the output from `free -m` to your question

Comment: I have added that to the question.

Comment: Adding some swap *might* help, or it might just make things slower.  You should use top and sort by RES or VIRT (f then arrow to the field and s q) and see what's eating all that memory.

Comment: Adding swap only slows down the computer when "used" goes near "total memory available". But when tehre is no swap, the computer no only works fine, but it also doesn't crash from lack of possibility to allocate memory. I did "systemctl start multi-user.targer" in two situations (when 1) i "used 30G out ot 32G" while in GUI and 2) after restart, in first case there was like 15G used (if I remember correctly) in 2) case it was only 2.8  GB used.  In both cases I have investigated top, and in both cases the applications that are running are virtually the same and they eat virtually the same RAM

Comment: I guess the "avilable" quantity is the key. Memory isn't freed, but can be freed when necessary. I have 128GB Debian machine at work. It had 3 GB used after restart. I opened Google chrome, I downloaded 150 GB file. the "used" memory after the download was 110 GB, after I closed the google chrome, it was 108GB. Same programs running and the usage can be 3GB or 108 GB. But there was  105GB "Available" in free -m. So this "used" is not really in use.